# How to check if cells are blank or not by comparing with other?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare 2 columns A and B where B has formula.

1. If ColumnA has extra data at the end and corresponding cells in column B is empty, then copy the Formula from above Row
2. If ColumnA is Empty and Column B has Formulas, then delete those Formulas!

Can we do this using VBA!?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: I agree with Peh. Postng as you did, is just you saying 'can someone write some code for me free?' As it is, I've done just that (see further below). But you really should have go yourself (even if it just recording stuff and seeing it you can make it work). Else, you'll likely get untested 'solutions'.

Comment: @Conan. In spite of the above, code solutions were provided. Could you now at least tell us if this is answered?

Comment: Hi ! Yes. I tried many ways but didn't get the expected result, so I posted my querry here. After all your answers I got a great base for my solution. Sorry for not posting my previous code here! Will post the one I implemented here. Thank you everyone for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Your question actually leaves more unspecified than specified. The followed does what you want in the broadest possible interpretation.

```
Sub Correspond_Columns()

    Const stMT$ = "Correspond Columns"
    Dim lgR&, lgLastFormulaRow
    
''' Pocess all rows from 1 down to the last used row
    For lgR = 1 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    ''' Get row number of lowest row with a formula in column B
        If Cells(lgR, 2).HasFormula Then lgLastFormulaRow = lgR
        
    ''' If cell in column A is not empty and there's no formula in corresponding column B:
    ''' o  If found row with formulas: Copy it to to here
    ''' o  Otherwise: Report and end
        If Cells(lgR, 1) <> "" Then
            If Not Cells(lgR, 2).HasFormula Then
                If lgLastFormulaRow > 0 Then
                    Cells(lgLastFormulaRow, 2).Copy
                    Cells(lgR, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
                Else
                    MsgBox Title:=stMT, Prompt:="Missing formula, but no preceding formula found"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
    
    ''' If cell in column A is empty: Clear whatever is in corresponding column B
        Else: Cells(lgR, 2).ClearContents
        End If
    Next lgR

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to check: this would be very easy to do by hand, using control to navigate to the bottom of a column, then double clicking the last formula in B to extend it along A, or shift-ctrl-down to select the remaining formulas in B and delete. But assuming you really do need to use VBA (perhaps you have many such files):

In VBA, it would be something like this: iterate down the column, check for both cells empty to end the loop. if A is empty, delete B; if B is empty, copy above function.

Assuming column A is column 1, B is 2:

```
Sub CheckEmptyColumns()
 i = 2
 Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1) AND IsEmpty(Cells(i,2)))
   If IsEmpty(Cells(i,1)) Then
      'A is empty, B is not: Clear B
      Cells(i,2).Clear
   ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(i,2)) Then
      'B is empty, A is not: copy formula
      Cells(i,2).FormulaR1C1 = Cells(i-1,2).FormulaR1C1
   i = i + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

Edit: if your formula uses relative cells, use Cells.FormulaR1C1 insead of Cells.Formula -- Thanks Spinner for the nudge.

Comment: Testing says the above doesn't work (at least not in the way I interpret the question).  "Cells(i,2).Formula= Cells(i-1,2).Formula" will transfer the formula as is (with original references). As the intent is 'copy of' the formula, we can reasonably assume references should reflect a 'copy and paste' outcome (not the original formula).

Comment: I was just changing that -- using .FormulaR1C1 should copy the relative formula. Thanks! And indeed, most likely they do want the 'relative' copy.

Comment: Yeah, ok. You have another issue: Say you just cleared the cell above in column b (per Cells(i,2).Clear), you then apply that (now empty) formula. Pretty sure that's not kicking a goal. :)

Comment: As described, there are only 3 states: A is longer, B is longer, or both end. So we would never copy the function *after* clearing, because that would imply A had stopped (B is cleared), then A started again. Certainly not an impossible thing in general, but not what was described in the question.

Comment: Maybe. But can't see (in the author's actual words) what you state above. As very reasonable leap of faith for sure. But not in the specification as such. :)